# How to extract dynamic website data with Google Script?

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script

I'd like to locate the exchange rate data from this website. I believe it is a so called dynamic website (Sorry, I am new to javascript) and the data is located somewhere else. May I know how to extract the exchange rates? (e.g. using Google sheets IMPORTXML function or extracting data by creating a new website with javascript)

Data link: http://www.amcm.gov.mo/en/financial-information/middle-rates

More information:
I used this code to fetch data from non-dynamic website in Google Sheets but it failed this time. After exploring the HTML, I found the data I want was generated by some Javascript in this webpage.

```
function getAMCMMidRate() {
  var link = 'http://www.amcm.gov.mo/zh/financial-information/middle-rates';
  var html = UrlFetchApp.fetch(link).getContentText();
  var doc = XmlService.parse(html);
  var html = doc.getRootElement();
  var menu = getElementById(html, 'result-table')[0];
  var output = XmlService.getRawFormat().format(menu);
  return output;
}
```

More information:

I tried with javascript today and it's my code. The result only contained the header of the table but not content. What should I do?

BTW, I found this code only work on IE but not on Chrome. I understood that it's CORS according to https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/. But I still couldn't get it work on Chrome with the code suggested by this website.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h2>Using the XMLHttpRequest Object</h2>

<div id="demo">
<button type="button" onclick="loadXMLDoc()">Change Content</button>
</div>

<script>

var myURL="http://www.amcm.gov.mo/en/financial-information/middle-rates";
function createCORSRequest(method, url){
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
if ("withCredentials" in xhr){
    xhr.open(method, url, false);
} else if (typeof XDomainRequest != "undefined"){
    xhr = new XDomainRequest();
    xhr.open(method, url);
} else {
    xhr = null;
}
return xhr;
}

function loadXMLDoc() {
var request = createCORSRequest("GET", myURL);
if (request){
    request.onload = function(){
        var parser = new DOMParser();
        var xmlDoc=parser.parseFromString(request.responseText,"text/html");
        var tds= xmlDoc.getElementById("result-table");
        document.getElementById("demo").appendChild(tds);
    };
    request.send();
    }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using pure javascript language, you can try [DOM HTML](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom.asp) to extract HTML tags and get whatever you like.
I recommend Jquery DOM for an alternative solution. Check it out https://api.jquery.com/category/miscellaneous/dom-element-methods/

Comment: kimdung, thanks for your reply. Are you talking about Xpath? I understand specific data in HTML tree can be extracted with IMPORTXML function in google sheets. But I found the data (exchange rate) is not directly located in the HTML file of the link. I am having trouble in finding the location of the data.

Comment: Xpath is another option. I haven't used it for a long time. Firstly, you can download that web page (*.html) to your local computer. Secondly, try to manually figure out an HTML tag in which id is "result-table". Everything you need in inside that element. Using DOM HTML or Jquery DOM to extract your data. Once, you have done, find another solution to get HTML content automatically in a specific time period.

Comment: I think manually download the webpage is not what I want. My goal is to extract this webpage content and email to me everyday automatically. I have added some code I tried today in the question.

Comment: Downloading the HTML page is a really first step having an input file for your coding.